# routing before button is clicked

Tags: controllers, routing

Hello, I have following problem with button and link where it redirects. Here is my button code:

```
$block->addButton('label', array(                           
                          'label' => 'Get Label',
                        //'onclick'   => ((Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("/label/setlabel")))),
                          'onclick'   => 'popWin();'                       
                        ));
```

I want open in new window my controller, for that I am using `'onclick'   => 'popWin();'` and this opens new window, but if I am adding `'onclick'   => ((Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("/label/setlabel")))),` it redirects me to controller page before I can even push button, as soon as I open the page where this button is, it automatically redirects me to controller page and doesn't show the page where the button is. How can I open the page where the button is and then click button and then it redirects to controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the onclick like this:

```
$url = Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("/label/setlabel");
...
"onclick" => "popWin('.$url.')"
```

I hope I got the quotes right.

Comment: tried, but when i click button happens - just nothing

Comment: if i do var_dump, i can see that the link is correct and link is also working

Comment: works if delete points like this: `"onclick" => "popWin('$url')"`

Comment: @user6398. Sorry for that. In my defense, I said to check the quotes :D